# absolute convergence of the series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^{n-1}\{(1+n^{-1})^n-1\}}{(z^n-1)\{z^n-(1+n^{-1})^n\}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

We need to prove the absolute convergence of the series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^{n-1}\{(1+n^{-1})^n-1\}}{(z^n-1)\{z^n-(1+n^{-1})^n\}}$.

Since

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^{n-1}\{(1+n^{-1})^n-1\}}{(z^n-1)\{z^n-(1+n^{-1})^n\}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\{(1+n^{-1})^n-1\}}{(z-\frac{1}{z^{n-1}})\{z^n-(1+n^{-1})^n\}}\\
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\{(1+n^{-1})^n-1\}}{z^{n+1}-(1+(1+n^{-1})^n)z+\frac{(1+n^{-1})^n}{z^{n-1}}},
\end{align*}

So if $|z|>1$, then the series $\approx \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\{(1+n^{-1})^n-1\}}{z^{n+1}}$, whose radius of absoulute convergence is 1, and so the series converges absolutely;

if $|z|<1$, then the series $\approx \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\{(1+n^{-1})^n-1\} z^{n-1}}{(1+n^{-1})^n}$, whose radius of absoulute convergence is 1, and so the series converges absolutely.

But the problem states that when $z=(1+\frac{1}{m})e^{2k\pi i/m}$ where $k=0,1,\dots, m-1; m=1,2,3,\dots$, we have $|z|>1$ and the series doesn't converge absolutely, which contradicts the above proof. Why?

Comment: Almost a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3721010).

Comment: Only power series have a radius of convergence. Your series is not a power series, but OK ...

Comment: I guess my proof is a bit too simple, what’s the way to prove it robustly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original expression

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^{n-1}\{(1+n^{-1})^n-1\}}{(z^n-1)\color{red}{\{z^n-(1+n^{-1})^n\}}}$$

we need

$$z^n-(1+n^{-1})^n \neq 0 \implies z^n \neq \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n \implies z\neq \left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)e^{2k\pi i/m}$$

for $m=1,\ldots,m-1$ with $m=1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: I see $z$ and $1+n^{-1}$ can’t be the root of same number

Comment: @CharlieChang Yes exactly!